# Global Build Events in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to have a "global" build event in SV2005?  What I mean by "global" is an event that will execute for all projects without having to specify the build event for each one.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a previous [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938864/solution-level-build-events-in-vs-2008) that outlines how to do it using Macros. The
answer is for Visual Studio 2008 but it will also work for Visual Studio 2005.