# Hook up solution level build events

Tags: build, solution, visual-studio-2012

I want to hook up solution level pre build / post build events in VS 2011 for .net projects.

My action includes firing up batch file. (it is working fine for any individual project, but i want it for solution build process).

How to achieve this?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938864/solution-level-build-events-in-vs-2008) that uses macro for the same. But macro are dropped in VS 2011.

Another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295454/visual-studio-solution-wide-pre-build-event) suggest makefile project, that it is specific to C++.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.buildevents%28v=vs.110%29) might be helpful. Take a look at that. You will have author a package for this though.